# field_attach_update stopped working - how to debug this?

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

I am using this simple code:

```
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$order->status='completed';
field_attach_update('commerce_order', $order);
```

To update the status of order to `completed`.

This code use to work but does not work anymore (the order status is not updated).

How to debug this ?

UPDATE:

Using :

```
entity_get_controller('commerce_order')->resetCache(array($order->order_id));
```

Does not work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't debug what ain't a bug :)

`status` is a property, not a field, of the commerce_order entity type - so it isn't affected by running `field_attach_update()`, which just saves field data, and avoids saving the entity itself.

You'll need to use `commerce_order_save()`, `entity_save()`, or manipulate the `commerce_order` table directly, and then clear the cache using the entity controller.

Comment: You beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Clive how is that this worked previously ?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer that - according to the code, it didn't.